# Finding linearly independent solutions of a underdetermined linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

Let Ax=b a random underdetermined linear system over GF(2) where A has dimensions mxn and n>>m. How many solutions of that system are linearly independent? Is there any efficient algorithm to find those solutions?

Thanks by your reply

Comment: The standard algorithm is row reduction of the augmented matrix.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard linear algebra, confer any introductory book on the subject. 
A system of linear equations can be solved by Gaussian elimination quite efficiently. In case you are worried about $\mathbb{F}_2$, well, you shouldn't be. Gaussian elimination works over any field. (In fact, it works in even more general setups.) If there exists a solution, then the dimension of the affine subspace of solutions is $n-\varrho(A)$, where $\varrho(A)$ is the rank of $A$.

Comment: I need to know HOW MANY SOLUTIONS of that system are LI.

Comment: As I said, it is standard theory. You should read up! Compute the rank of $A$, subtract it from $n$, and raise 2 to this power. Provided that there exists a solution this is the number of solutions. But this answer is no help to you if you do not read the introductory part of the literature.

Comment: I need only the solutions that are linearly independent in a random linear underdetermined linear system over GF(2).